# Variable greater than

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a variable in Python that is equal to any number greater than another number? For example:

```
x = >26
```

pretty much for those who are wondering what i am trying to do I am trying to make it so if a  number in a list of integers is over 26 then take that number and change it to a number under 26 depending on what number it is. Sorry this is one small thing in a bigger project so its hard to explain it all

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__

Comment: No, but you could make a lambda. `f = lambda x: x >=26` then use `if f(12): ...` EDIT: nm, use the rich objects @JeremyBanks recommended.

Comment: What's the use case? Why do you need this magic variable, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Bill and I interpreted your question differently. Could you indicate which you meant? A magic variable that can be compared, or a single random value satisfying your criteria?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [you can customize your class's behaviour in comparison operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to get this behaviour.

```
class EqualToAnyGreaterThan(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other > self.n

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return other <= self.n


egt26 = EqualToAnyGreaterThan(26)

print egt26 ==  1 # False
print egt26 == 26 # False 
print egt26 == 27 # True 
print egt26 == 99 # True

print 21 == egt26 # False
print 89 == egt26 # True

print 21 != egt26 # True
print 89 != egt26 # False
```

Comment: Brilliant idea! never thought of doing it this way!

Answer (score 1):

obviously we can't do every number greater than 26 because that's infinity but there are a couple options.

```
x = xrange(27, int(1e7)) #will return a generator of 27, 10000000
```

Comment: lol true i guess i could do this